# Magento 1.9 Login Problem With Chorme

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-login

I know this question has been answered 100s times but non of them solved this issue.

There is no problem accessing admin panel from other browsers but Chorme.

When I clear cookies(F12>Resources>Cookies) I can Login to dashboard.

table value and Core file also been modified.

But still  no luck. Can you help me with this?

[image: magento admin login with chorme]

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome

Comment: What hostname are you trying to use?  Magento requires that the hostname have at least one period in it (eg mydomain.dev).

Comment: Thanks @JoeConstant, Sorry didn't get what does "hostname have at least one period in it", if it is /app/etc/local.xml that is set as<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>,

Comment: Further Cookie Lifetime=3360000

Comment: That host is the DB host. I mean what hostname are you using in the browser?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri, already tried all of these

Comment: @JoeConstant, https://example.com

Comment: Are you working on multiple sites using that hostname? I've seen before where multiple installations on the same base domain name can cause problems with logging in to the admin and only clearing cookies allows you to login

Comment: No, there is only one installation

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, but I do not think it is a permanent solution. Set your cookie lifetime to 0. It makes it never expire, so Chrome will not end your session.

It was very odd, when I did try to login, it would show my saved items in the cart, but my user was not logged in. Could not access my account.